# How to clean or clean build my Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans, build

I'm using [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) in my Java project. in [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) there are build and clean build icons but there aren't in [IntellIJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). How can I clean or clean build my project in it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer here with the most votes suggests running the `clean` and `install` Lifecycle items separately in IntelliJ, which is easy enough and works. But it’s worth mentioning that you can combine these steps (and/or others) by instead creating a new *Run/Debug Configuration* of type `maven` and adding the command `clean install` (or whichever combination of maven lifecycle methods you run on a recurring basis).

Thereafter, running a `mvn clean install` is as simple as clicking the green button to run that *Run/Debug Configuration*.

[image]

Comment: should the configuration be created for each project/module?
OR is there any variable we can use for "Working directory" which resolves to current active project/module path? using things like $MODULE_IML_DIR$, $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ didn't work for me

Answer (score 41):

## Maven > Lifecycle > clean

Open the `Maven Projects` panel. Click lower-left corner for pop-up menu if that panel is not already visible.

In that panel, open the `Lifecycle` item. There you will find `clean` and `install` items for you to run.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ > Maven > Lifecycle > clean]

As commented, you can also invoke this by command-line/console. But if already using IntelliJ, I do not see the point. Just show/hide this pane as you work. I use it countless times a day to hit `install` to build complete app, and hit `clean` whenever I suspect not all of the project is up-to-date in the build-results.

## `Build` > `Rebuild Project`

If you are having weird problems in running the app in development also try the menu item `Build` > `Rebuild Project`.

I have asked [what is the difference between a `Build` > `Rebuild Project` versus doing a Maven `clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283035/642706). But I still do not understand the precise details. So when things seem wonky, I do both to right the ship.

Tips:

- Restarting IntelliJ may help when behavior seems odd.
- Keep Intellij updated.

Comment: You can also invoke this from the intelij terminal by typing 'mvn clean'

Comment: And the terminal window can be made visible by "Select --  View | Tool Windows | Terminal from the main menu."   Upvote for answer and comment.

Comment: @Silmarilos your comment should be made an answer, imo your method is much more accessible.

Comment: You can find a video on Rebuild Project here: https://youtu.be/UqvHA-E5Jyw

Answer (score 16):

Here is a faster way to do that:

in IntelliJ IDEA window hit `Ctrl` key twice, then a pop-up window appears like this:

[image]

there you can enter your command and use recommendation tools, too.
including template commands and the list of your previous ones:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In IntelliJ, go to your Toobar, **View**>**Tools Windows**>**Maven Projects**

From there, you can click Clean to clean the project

[image]

Answer (score 4):

click on maven panel --> select project--> lifecycle --> double click clean.

[image]

source: vaadin.com

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I found some suggestions but nothing get me to an acceptable solution. Here are some things I found maybe it will help you:

File -> Invalidate caches / restart

or just rebuild the project: Build -> Rebuild project (Shift+F11)
But it's nothing like Clean or Clean and Build from netbeans.

By the way I use intellij-15.

**Edit:** Finally, Build->Build Artifacts->Build or Rebuild works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i think rebuild project is so different with clean or clean build. is that true?

Comment: Yes, I think it is very different. But these two things are the only suggestions I found after hours of research and none of them are working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Maven project:

1. Go to your project's root folder (where your pom.xml is located)
2. In address bar of **windows** explorer type **cmd**
3. You should be prompted with **cmd** window where you should type `mvn clean`
4. That will clean your target folder which is getting created after build

Make sure you have your system variables set so `mvn` commands can work (otherwise you will get "`mvn is not recognized` as an internal or external command")

This is how it should look:
[image: screenshotCMD]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [Jetbrains help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html#run_goal) there are three ways to execute maven goals in IntelliJ.
One simple way to execute clean and install and also save the configuration is to select with CTRL button the goals "clean" and "install" from the maven tab -> Right click in one of the selected -> Modify Run Configuration -> check all the fields -> click OK. Then you can execute this configuration in order to clean and install.

Answer (score 1):

So far, the best I can come up with (for a non-Maven project) would be to manually delete the target folder and then do your build.  But I'm still looking for a better answer, myself.

I'm building a Maven project, and I discovered if I run the Maven Clean phase from the IntelliJ "Maven Projects" pane, it deletes the target folder.  The target folder itself (without subfolders) corresponds to NetBeans' dist folder, and the subfolders in target have corresponding subfolders of the build folder in NetBeans.  When you clean and build in NetBeans, the first thing that happens is the build folder and dist folder are deleted, and this corresponds to deleting the target folder in IntelliJ, so that's why I suggest it.

Note that just as you get an error if you try to clean and build in NetBeans while holding open a file that happens to be in the build or dist directory, you will similarly get an error in IntelliJ if you try to execute the Maven Clean phase while a file is open in the target folder - the difference is, if you are doing this in Windows, IntelliJ will half-way delete the folder and there isn't a simple straightforward way to clean up the mess even after you close the program that is holding the file open.  Probably if you reboot it will clean up, but who wants to do that?  I ended up identifying the culprit process (processes, actually - two copies of explorer.exe) with Sysinternals Process Explorer, killing all instances of explorer (killing only the two culprits didn't seem to work), then starting explorer back up via Task Manager, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal to switch to the current project directory and use `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 1):

This way works for the `InteliJ IDEA 14` upwards not exceeding `InteliJ IDEA 20`:

```
Click Run -> Edit Configurations -> Press + -> Search for "Maven" -> Locate "Command Line" field and enter in following maven commands "clean install" ->  Press OK.
```

Now click the green button to run that Run/Debug Configuration, this will `maven clean install` the module/project.

The output of the module if you are to deploy somewhere can be seen in the `target` directory in the project.

`Maven Clean Install` refers to clear any compiled files you have, making sure that you're really compiling each module from scratch