# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, file, intellij-14

I am trying to set the configuration location for my Project but I keep getting the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [main/resources/app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist

I have my project set up like this:

[image]

And I have my code set up as:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configLocation: "main/resources/app-context.xml");
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: post the code and error log here. NOT in images

Comment: Sorry about that! Will do for future questions!

Comment: try to clean your build. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409788/how-to-clean-or-clean-build-my-maven-project-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you put directly under `src/main/java` is in the default package, at the root of the classpath. It's the same for resources put under `src/main/resources`: they end up at the root of the classpath.

So the path of the resource is `app-context.xml`, not `main/resources/app-context.xml`.

Comment: how can add files or update later this resource file when server is running?

Comment: @Kenji you can't. Resources are application resources, known at compilation time and bundled with the app. If you want to add files later, then those files are not application resources, but data. Data goes in your database, whataver it is (it could be your file system).

Comment: I want to put a json file for my mobile app version ( force update or not). so if I could just put a json file and update it in public static root, it seems better than create an table for just one record. what is your idea?

Comment: What if I want to locate a file on the same level as "src", in a directory called report?

Answer (score 8):

We can also try this solution

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:app-context.xml");
```

in this the spring automatically finds the class in the class path itself

Comment: It also seems to work for Spring Boot with `@ImportResource("classpath*:config.xml")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

The file location/path has to relative to your classpath locations. If resources directory is in your classpath you just need "app-context.xml" as file location.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");`

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse -
Follow the path `Build path -> Configure build path -> go to sources -> add folder`
mark the resource folder where you have your XML file.
Now if you try to run it will run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to read resources. It will give input stream.

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("files.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was running some tests and was facing these errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load JSON from class path resource [com/springproject/cashcard/expected.json]
and
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/springproject/cashcard/expected.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

so, i noticed that the `test/resources` module was missing. So i added it to the class path, added the JSON file and did a project rebuild and it worked.
[image]