# Spring3.2 web project in tomcat 6 upgrade to tomcat 8,classpath*:/**/*.hbm.xml cannot be opend because it does not exists

Tags: spring, tomcat8, tomcat6

This's old project use Spring 3.2.4 Struts2 and Hibernate,run in Tomcat6.Now change use jdk1.8 Tomcat6 is no problem,but use Tomcat8 have some problem,it's about as follows.
    In sessionFactory config  name mappingResources use  asterisk wildcard to find hbm.xml file,the console have Error cannot be opened because it dose not exist.
    How can i resolve this problem?Please answer me thank you very much.

Code：

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
    <value>classpath*:/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863382/java-io-filenotfoundexception-class-path-resource-cannot-be-opened-because-it-d)