# WebDriverWait depreciated no longer working for implicit waits

Tags: java, selenium

When the api was depreciated they added 3 contstructors from what I can see on selenium documentation page.

When I type this the complier cant find duration.ofSeconds(10), the reason for that is inside the WebDriverWait class only the old depreciated contsructors are showing which doesnt make sense because on the selenium documentation page it shows 3 new constructors they have replaced the depreciated ones with.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Here is the documentation I read it from showing how there are 3 new constructors replacing the old ones
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.get(), Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

This constructor is available from selenium 4.0,0 only you can add maven as :

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>
```

you should clean project,  rebuild and do maven install again

All documentations are updated as per selenium :

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/issues/627

Comment: I am currently using that same version of selenium in a jar file, refreshed and restarted my pc to no avail...

Comment: you should rebuild the project and it works fine ,

Comment: whichIDE are you using

Comment: I am using Inteliji

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409788/how-to-clean-or-clean-build-my-maven-project-in-intellij-idea

Comment: I am not running a maven project

Comment: Which build tool are you using reimport Selenium, clean the project

Comment: I am using ANT to build